# How to connect sql developer to Oracle database using instant client_12_1

Tags: oracle

I have downloaded the oracle instant client 12_1 but i'm unable to connect to the oracle database.when i tried using sql developer it is displaying the following error.

The Network could not be established.

I'm using windows 7 and my Oracle_home path is defautly set in the system variables as

path

E:\app\dell\product\11.2.0\dbhome\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

Comment: that oracle home path of E:\app\dell does not look like a standard install, are you sure it's right?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you've begun the headache of messing with the connection string.  I seriously recommend you find the option in SQL Developer that will allow you to connect directly to the server (bypass TNSNAMES) and use EZ Connect.  The connection string will look like this:

```
server.whatevz.com:port/sidname
```

I don't use SQL Developer, so I can't point to it specifically, but I have used it and configured it as such, and it works fine.  I'm a fan of PL/SQL Developer (All Around Automation) myself.